Netsuite suite script not working and not loading iframe content inside Netsuite portlet
Netsuite portlet application not loading my suitescript. My script defined as below
/**
 * @NScriptType Portlet
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 */
define(['N/log','N/record'], function(log,record) {
    function render(context) {
            context.portlet.title = 'Test Form Portlet';
           url = 'https://app.acceptance.com/panel/public/launch/suite.html';
           context.portlet.html = "<iframe id='paneldata' style='width: 100%; height: 150px;     margin:0; border:0; padding:0' src='" + url + "'>";
        
        }

    return {
        render: render
    };
});

In portlet I am getting error as below so please provide way to solve this issue.
A User Error Has Occurred
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_INVALID_UI_OBJECT_TYPE","message":"That operation is not supported for this type of UI object: form. It is only supported for type: html.","id":"","stack":["Error\n at Object.render (/SuiteScripts/suiteletscript_catchrecord.js:9:13)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"SSS_INVALID_UI_OBJECT_TYPE","details":"That operation is not supported for this type of UI object: form. It is only supported for type: html.","userEvent":null,"stackTrace":["Error\n at Object.render (/SuiteScripts/suiteletscript_catchrecord.js:9:13)"],"notifyOff":false},"notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}
expectation is inside my netsuite portlet url load properly with the content present in that url.

This error occurs because the value returned by the script does not match the Portlet Type setting in the script record.  Change the Portlet Type setting on your script record from Simple Form to Inline HTML and refresh the portlet.
